# spring-boot: start application without database if password fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I am using the application in two instances that have different database passwords. My code only needs to access and query one instance, and doesn't need to access database on another instance. If I try to deploy the app with wrong password, it gives me "password authentication" error and doesn't start the application.

I want the app to ignore the database connection if password authentication is failed.

Here is my application.properties file.

```
spring.security.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false

## Postgresql for storing backup details
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
#spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.datasource.primary.continueOnError=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Spring boot version is 1.5.9

Comment: Very interesting, If the database authentication fails the connection pools also fail to initialize and the application will not start. What you're asking are reattempts to authenticate until a successful one?

Comment: @garfield, no what I am asking is exclude database/datasource connection if the authentication fails. So even if the authentication fails, the app should still be able to start (even if it cannot do any database operations)

Answer (score 1):

You can run spring boot application without datasource. For that you must disable the auto configuration of datasource and probably the JPA auto configuration as well. Place the below line in your `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: but this will disable it for the entire application. I want the same war file to run on two instances, one where I need the database, and another where I don't.

Comment: @user2798227 in this case the application could have two different profiles one the normal one and the second one as jusermar10 has suggested.

Comment: Yes, but I will be deploying this in 100 other instances, so I will need to create 100 other profiles where I will need to maintain their database connection details even though I don't want to connect/access their databases. I was hoping for a solution where it still starts the application even if the database password authentication fails at startup.

Comment: @user2798227 I see the property `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` commented out in your properties file. Is it not working? when I set that property, my spring boot app starts fine after the `password authentication failed` error.

Comment: Not sure why it didnt work for you. Could you please post your `pom.xml` to check.